# Can we choose whether to receive the email for daily answers only if we haven't seen the answers?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

When I ask questions on the sites I often check the "Notify me@example.com daily of any new answers"

I wouldn't call myself a power user but I do check back on the site often and can't remember ever seeing an answer in the email that I haven't already seen. I'd like some way of only receiving the email with answers in that I haven't already viewed.

Sure, I could just not tick the box but I don't want to miss something.

So I'd like to choose whether to receive the email for daily answers only if we haven't seen the answers on the site?

Funnily enough I have ticked the notify box on this question!

Comment: Define "seen the answer". This might seem dumb - but what if your question has multiple pages of answers, and you only looked at one page - what if the pages were sorted in a non-default way? What if when you visited the site an answer was deleted that has since been undeleted? I suspect this kind of notification would be non-trivial to implement.

Comment: While it might be difficult, this is something I've wished for on every heavy-use website I've ever used, especially Facebook, where it totally should be possible because clicking on the notification link on the site ought to be cake as an event to tie it to. SO is no direct comparison, but it might be an indicator that it can be done if the change/post is effectively *linked to* (and then the color fading thing fires and the whole shebang). If I click on that--and not just visit the URL it's on--maybe that's a sign-off.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger Google Reader knows when I've seen a post and in this context we could imagine each post on Google Reader to be an answer.